# Why is file_put_contents and serialize only adding part of serialize even if the data is coming in?

Tags: php

I am trying to add an object with data in another class and then serializing to a data file. When I look at the data file only 2 characters are added "b:0;", and they are always the same no matter how much I change the object contents and also when I try adding more posts the file stays the same.

I tried changing the object to a normal string and the result was the same (the same two characters "b:0;". I also tried checking if the function was getting the right input.

This is my constructor in the Post class:

```
function __construct($nam, $mess, $dat){
        $this->name = $nam;
        $this->message = $mess;
        $this->date = $dat;
    }
```

this is my array and function i am using inside guestbook class:

```
protected $PostList = [];
function addPost($nam, $mes, $dat){
    $obj = new Post($nam, $mes, $dat);
    array_push($this->PostList, $obj);
    // Serialize and save all of the new object array to file
    file_put_contents("guestbook/Postdata.txt", serialize($this->PostList));
}
```

The expected result on the data file was something like this?

```
a:size:{key definition;value definition;(repeated per element)}
```

but all i get is "b:0;"

Here is where i use my class on index.php:

```
<?php
$guestbook = new Guestbook();
if (isset($_REQUEST['addpost'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['author'])  && isset($_POST['message'])){    
        if ($_REQUEST['author'] != ""  && $_REQUEST['message'] != "") {

            $guestbook->addPost($_REQUEST["author"], $_REQUEST["message"], Date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        }
    }

    unset($_REQUEST["addpost"]);
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

?>

SOLUTION:
file_exists() was always true and by that, I was inserting a bool value in my array. So I solved by using the function filesize("filepath"); instead.

Comment: Can you include the code where you are using this class?

Comment: Yes, just realized that I missed that!

Comment: For the record, `b:0;` is the serialized version of `false`.

Comment: @AllamoOlsson What is the output of `var_dump($this->PostList);` before your `file_put_contents/serialize` line?

Comment: I get (bool)false, so somehow I don't get the data in the array?

Comment: Pretty strange, the code as presented appears correct. I haven't been able to replicate: https://repl.it/repls/ClearPungentCommas

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same. I don't understand why it isn't working. I tried using echo as you did but it still prints false, before that I print the name, message, and date and the variables enter the function correctly.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you pushing the object onto an array before serialising? It's also worth noting that `file_put_contents` will overwrite the contents of `guestbook/Postdata.txt` every time `addPost` is called (unless you pass `FILE_APPEND` as the third argument).

Comment: I push every post into the array then I serialize the array into the file, it shouldn't matter that I don't have FILE_APPEND since my constructor reads the files into the array everytime the page is loaded. Because if I create 10 posts the array will be 10 big and then I can just serialize everything and in the same way unserialize. The page is loaded after every addpost clicked. FILE_APPEND just gives me two false in this case

Comment: Alright so I tried creating a variable with the incoming name, message and date and using that for unserialize and it works... There must be an error with my array or something but have, do you have any thoughts on that @DarraghEnright?

Comment: I have also checked if my object has the variables, and like I thought they are there and it works sending each at the time, there must be something wrong with the array.

Comment: Ah, now this is interesting. I think you need to post the code that reads the file and assigns it to `Guestbook::$Postlist`. Are you using `file_get_contents()`? It returns `false` when it cannot read a file—sounds like that's the source of your error.

Comment: @DarraghEnright alright i found the problem is in the reading. i am using file_get_contents yes.
this seems to read it right:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187810/discussion-between-allamo-olsson-and-darragh-enright).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the way I was reading the file.
Here is how it looked:

```
             if(file_exists("data.txt")>0){
             //$this->PostList = unserialize(file_get_contents("data.txt"));
            array_push($this->PostList, unserialize(file_get_contents("data.txt") ) );
            var_dump($this->PostList);
        }
```

the file_exists function was always being true since the file existed and the array was loading a false value at first so to solve that i changed to:

```
if(filesize("data.txt")){
          //...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but you setup the __construct($nam, $mess, $dat) but you are passing it to addPost($nam, $mes, $dat).  If you are missing the message, either change it to mess or mes, or wouldn't hurt if you had $name, $message, $date just for clarity, but make the change in both

Comment: The reason I did not do that is that I have had so much trouble with PHP, that for me don't make sense. I did not want them to have the same name but I understand your point.